# Can I use indexOf(input)?

Tags: javascript

```
function myFunction(input){
var number_of_images = input.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("img")
var image_clicked = number_of_images.indexOf(input)
alert ("you clicked on image number "+image_clicked)
}
```

I am building a rating scale with three images. I want to communicate the user which of the three images he´s clicked on. I have onClick events on all three images onClick(this). Then, I am trying to use indexOf(input), where input is refers to the parameter (this) passed from an onclick(this). It´s not working. ¿Any alternative suggested? Thanks.

Comment: There is no `getElementByTagName` function.

Comment: Further to Bergi's comment: what you're looking for (I assume) is [`getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName).

Comment: have some kind of attribute on the images for example ID = 1,2,3.... In your alert do a gettAttribute()... to display what the user has clicked on

Comment: @Bergi, you´re right, it´s getElementsByTagName, just corrected the question, thanks :). However, that´s not the reason why the function is not working.

Comment: @DavidThomas, you´re right, it´s getElementsByTagName, just corrected the question, thanks :). However, that´s not the reason why the function is not working. Any suggestions?

Comment: @TabiVicuna: No, it is not. Have a look at my answer :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `indexOf` on it will not work because the result is a (live) [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/NodeList), and does not provide Array methods. Yet, you can still apply the [Array `indexOf` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) on the node list (by using the [`.call` Function met](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)), as it is generic:

```
var images = input.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("img");
var index = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(images, input);
```

Notice that older IEs do not support indexOf, you will need to [shim it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Compatibility).

Comment: It works, thanks a lot @Bergi. I am new here. I guess I now should click on the tick and upvote? Again, thanks.